# Create an hidden Xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, hidden

I created an XML file but the problem is that i need it to be an **hidden** file,

Now I see the XML file in the folder, can click it etc.

my code: (this is the creation of the xml file)

```
XDocument doc; 
doc = 
   new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
   new XElement("files"));
doc.Save(xmlPath);`
```

How can I change it?

Comment: How "hidden" do you want it to be? Just in normal file-system terms?

Comment: @JonSkeet post the answer,I love to give my vote 2 u

Comment: @JonSkeet waiting for your answer :)

Comment: @Rakitić: How can I answer when the OP hasn't clarified the question? We don't know why they want it to be hidden, or how secure it has to be. If a simple hidden file is enough, that's fine - but that's pretty poor protection for anything important.

Comment: Agreeing to the fact that the OP hasn't framed the question properly...but it looks like the OP wants it to be "simply hidden"...

Comment: @JonSkeet, you have right but we do not except a lot of decription from the newbie. I do not know, if he will answer or not, just write the both use cases and we will votes!

Comment: As @BassamAlugili said....write both the cases...at least we get to learn something new from you :)

Comment: @BassamAlugili: No, I won't answer a badly-asked question; it's not a good idea to encourage users that way. You may not expect new users to ask good questions, but I hope to hold them to a reasonable standard.

Comment: @JonSkeet you have right! agree with 100%  but you will get my votes for your good answers!

Comment: @BassamAlugili: No, I'm still not going to answer a question which is too vague to be answered well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(xmlPath);
  // Hide the file.
  File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
  Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is now hidden.", path);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot
I really appreciate your help

Comment: u are welcome mark it as answer plz, if it is really helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can save over your file, if it is Hidden or Readonly, you have to fix (unhide) the permissions first.  So you need to do something like this:

```
private void RemoveHiddenNReadOnly()
{
    if (File.Exists) // File here is the FileInfo of the xml file for the class
    {
        File.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden; // Remove Hidden Flag 
        File.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly; // Remove ReadOnly Flag
    }
}
```

Then save the file, and then set the hidden flag again.

```
doc.Save(File.FullName); 
File.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes("data.xml");

//To Hide the file
File.SetAttributes("data.xml", File.GetAttributes("data.xml") | FileAttributes.Hidden);

//and to unhide the file
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
    File.SetAttributes("data.xml", attributes);
}
```

the "data.xml" in this case is lacated in the debug folder but you could change it for a path where your file is located -> String path =  "C:\Users\User\App....\filename.ext"